# Validating fileupload(image Dimensions) in Backend Octobercms

Tags: laravel, validation, file-upload, octobercms

im creating a plugin where im using fileupload field type in Backend. I have an realation $attachOne and i need to validade image dimensions(height and width), is ther a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to add validation logic to the model. Where the relation is called `somerelation`, define a method like this in the model class:

```
public function beforeValidate()
{
    $file = $this->somerelation()->withDeferred($this->sessionKey)->first();
    $filename = $file->getLocalPath();
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

    if ($width < 800) {
        throw new ValidationException(['somerelation' => 'Width must be greater than 800']);
    }
}
```

For this method override to work, make sure the model already uses the `October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation` trait. For it only to occur in the backend, a quick check of `App::runningInBackend()` should do the trick.

- [More information on October Model events](http://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#events)

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will give width and height of the image.

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
```